# Variable substitution not working in CGI script

Tags: debian, bash, apache2, cgi

I am trying to make a CGI script that takes the name and email from a form, decodes the QUERY_STRING variable into the two values, and then does stuff with them ( for now I just decoded the name an I was trying to output it in the browser just to see that it works).
The code is written in bash and it looks like this:

```
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
name=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | awk '{split($0,array,"&")} END{print array[1]}' | awk '{split($0,array,"=")} END{print array[2]}'`
cat <<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>Welcome to our application</title>
</head>
<body>
        <p>Welcome $name </p>
</body>
</html>
EOT
```

The problem is, whenever the code gets run after I give the inputs through the form, instead of printing in the web browser (for example) "Welcome Jon", it print "Welcome $name", basically not doing the substitution like it should.

Things I have tried:

1. I tried to echo the name variable outside the html as well and got nothing, so there might be a problem with the awk statements but I can't figure out what it is for the life of me.
2. Tried deleting the second awk and finally got an expected result as the browser printed name=Jon for the echo, but for the html part it still printed "Welcome $name".

Potentially useful info:

-I have the debian 12 distribution and I have set up the cgid module for apache.

-In the form I have specified the get method for the name and email and when I tried to print the QUERY_STRING variable as is, it worked.

I am pretty much a beginner with both linux and CGI scripts so any piece of advice is welcomed with open arms. Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's weird. What happens if you add the shebang: `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Answer (score 0):

Tangentially, bash can parse the query string:

```bash
declare -A data
while IFS='=' read -r -d '&' key value; do
  data["$key"]=$value
done <<<"${QUERY_STRING}&"
```

Then, you can use `${data[name]}` in the heredoc.